# show the section based on page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created filter section with filter.blade.php.I have 5 selectbox in that page.I want to display only four in page1 and 5 selectbox section in page2.

In web.php

```
Route::get('/page1',array('middleware'=>'checksession',function(){return View('layouts.page1');}));
Route::get('/page2',array('middleware'=>'checksession',function(){return View('layouts.page2');}));
```

I want to display below selectbox only in page2

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Card header -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingFive5">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseFive5"
           aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive5">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <div id="username_view">Username</div>
                <img src="img/chevron-down.png" class="fa-angle-down rotate-icon">
            </h5>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pass the `page` specific options for the filter as the second argument for the view?

Comment: I'm sure a `laravel get page name` search on google would show you plenty of examples :)

Comment: Name your routes and check which route you're on `{{ Route:is('NAMEOFROUTE2') }}`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it like you are able to pass pass your current route variable as the second argument of your view.

```
Route::get('/page2',array('middleware'=>'checksession',function(){
$route = Route::current();
return View('layouts.page2',, compact('route'));
}));
```

after this pass condition over the route variable to satisfy your need.

another way is you are able to check this in your blade template directly by this:

```
@if(Request::url() === 'your url here')
// code
@endif
```

i hope this guide you. Read this for more understanding [Accessing The Current Route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route)